# In C, is it guaranteed that 1/2 == 0?

Tags: c, arrays, math, integer, binary-search

Is it guaranteed in C that `1/2 == 0`? I need that for an implementation of binary search:

```
/*
 * len is the array length
 * ary is an array of ptrs
 * f is a compare function
 * found is a ptr to the found element in the array
 * both i and offset are unsigned integers, used as indexes
 */

for(i = len/2; !found && i < len; i += offset) {
    res = f(c->ary[i]);

    if (res == 0) {
        found = c->ary[i];
    }
    else {
        offset = (res < 0 ? -1 : 1) * (i/2);
        if (!offset) {
            i = len+1;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, this is guaranteed.  According to the C ISO spec, §6.5.5/5:

> The result of the / operator is the quotient from the division of the first operand by the
>   second;

The quotient of 1 / 2 is 0, so `1 / 2 == 0` is guaranteed to be true in C.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'd suggest you refrain from answering obvious duplicates in the future...

Comment: @H2CO3- I'm sorry... I didn't realize this was a duplicate. I actually thought it was really interesting because in every C implementation I've ever seen I know that division is integer division, but I didn't know whether the C spec guaranteed this. I hoped that this answer would provide an authoritative reference beyond "it works on every compiler I've ever tried it on."

Comment: Fair point. The standard guarantees this, but beware: such simple questions are *generally* already asked and answered, even multiple times.